# Retry is executed only once in Spring Cloud Stream Reactive

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

When I try again in Spring Cloud Stream Reactive, a situation that I don't understand arises, so I ask a question.
In case of sending String type data per second, after processing in s-c-stream Function, I intentionally caused RuntimeException according to conditions.

```
@Bean
    fun test(): Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>?> = Function{ input ->
        input.map { sellerId ->
            if(sellerId == "I-ZICGO")
                throw RuntimeException("intentional")
            else
                log.info("do normal: {}", sellerId)
                sellerId
        }.retryWhen(Retry.from { companion ->
            companion.map { rs ->
                if (rs.totalRetries() < 3) { // retrying 3 times
                    log.info("retry!!!: {}", rs.totalRetries())
                    rs.totalRetries()
                }
                else
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(rs.failure())
            }
        })
    }
```

However, the result of running the above logic is:

```
2021-02-25 16:14:29.319  INFO 36211 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'consumer.processingSellerItem-in-0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-02-25 16:14:29.322  INFO 36211 --- [container-0-C-1] k.c.m.c.service.impl.ItemServiceImpl     : retry!!!: 0
2021-02-25 16:14:29.322  INFO 36211 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'consumer.processingSellerItem-in-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

Retry is processed only once.

Should I change from reactive to imperative to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. The retry settings are meaningless for reactive functions. You can see a more details explanation on the similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304153/spring-cloud-stream-reactive-handling-messages-exception/66304691#66304691)